# Android Market gone after emulator reboot

Tags: google-play-store, android-emulator

I have installed Android Market on Android Emulator successfully using steps mention in [[How to] Install Android market on Emulator](http://blog.varunkumar.me/2010/11/how-to-install-android-market-in-google.html)

Market is installed without any issue but after emulator reboot Market is gone.

Can anyone help me in solving this problem?

**SPECS**

- OS=Ubuntu 10.04
- Android-SDK=2.3.3(API Level 10)
- Eclipse Indigo

**AVD Details:**

> Name: AVD
>
> CPU/ABI: ARM(armeabi)
>
> Path: /home/ma/.android/AVD.avd
>
> Target: Android 2.3.3 (API level 10)
>
> Skin: HVGA
>
> SD Card: 512M
>
> hw.lcd.density: 160
>
> vm.heapSize: 24
>
> hw.ramSize: 256

Comment: Can show the details of your emulator?

Comment: @JPM: Added Details.

Answer (score 4):

The Android emulator is resetting the system image when rebooting. You can find the changed version of the system.img in your `/tmp` here:

`/tmp/android-username/`

It usually has a name like `emulator-*`. Copy that file before shutting down the emulator.

Comment: I searched my system for that file but no luck. I got windows 10

Answer (score 3):

When you restart the emulator make sure that "Wipe use data"  is not checked.  Also update the SDK to the latest.  Not sure but I remember some issues with the emulator and user data on older versions.

Comment: "Wipe use data" is not checked.

Comment: What revision # is your SDK Tools and SDK Platform tools?

Comment: android-sdk_r13-linux_x86

Answer (score 3):

Installing the market in the emulator is not that simple because by default the system partition is resettet on every reboot of the emulator.

If you want to make the changes permanent you have to delete the file `/system/app/SdkSetup.apk`

If you copy afterwards the two necessary files `GoogleServicesFramework.apk` and `Vending.apk` to `/system/app/` you will have an working market inside the emulator.

Hence, using the adb shell you have to execute the following commands:

```
mount -o remount rw /system
rm /system/app/SdkSetup.apk
adb push Vending.apk /system/app/
adb push GoogleServicesFramework.apk /system/app/
```

BTW: The necessary APKs can be found here: [CyanogenMod Wiki Latest Version/Google Apps](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Latest_Version/Google_Apps)

Comment: I already did that, but no effect. Removed the SdkSetup.apk but on reboot everything all the changes reverted back.